# Reflection = Rotation about a planar axis

Tags: group-theory, permutations, symmetry

For a Dihedral group $D_{2n}$, the operation of reflection about an axis, that is in the same plane as the polygon, can be considered as a rotation in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$.

For e.g. for a square, the diagonal is the planar axis about which we rotate the square in the $z$-axis.

The commonly used rotation is about the $z$-axis passing through the center of the polygon. Then, doesn't it imply that there is no 'reflection operation'?

Of course, for the Dihedral group, we consider typically the axis passing through the vertices of the polygon rather than any edges, since the final shape orientation is preserved.

The way it's been picturized in say "Dummit & Foote, Abstract Algebra" it seems reflection is somewhat a "separate" operation. It would have been more intuitive to understand them as rotation in the plane of the polygon & rotation about the orthogonal axis, passing through the center to the plane of the polygon...

This kind of gels well if we study the symmetry of 3D or higher objects with respect to the "orthogonal to 3-D" axis passing through the center and the available axis in the dimension of the object that preserves structure.
Appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: Please format and split your Q into paragraphs

Comment: Any isometry in an $n$-dimensional space can be realized as a rotation in an $(n+1)$-dimensional space. Even more: any group of isometry in $n$ dimensions can be realized as a group of rotations in $n+1$ dimensions.

Comment: If you think of a square as living in 3D-space then, sure, you can rotate it about its diagonal. Do observe that the rotation then swaps the front and back sides of the square. This is because a (proper) rotation always preserves handedness, whereas a reflection reverts the handedness. You can fix that by introducing an extra dimension (as explained by Captain Lam), but I don't see much point in doing that. Handedness reversing isometries cannot be totally ignored.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks! Just my opinion is that we are unwittingly introducing physical restrictions ( like the assumption of the existence of Mirror & its behavior or the concept of motion - even for rotation which relies on induced force etc.) into Math. It may be useful to consider them as parametrized homotopies of vertices or retractions. Just my thought